# NA's After pivot_wider in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyr

I have seen some post about my problem but I think mine is a bit different. I tried to follow the solutions, but all to no avail.
Initially, I did a `pivot_longer` for a data set of `176 column` and there were no NA's when i did `summary(df)`.
The dataset after `pivot_longer` looks like this:

```r
region transportation_type country date value

Albania driving Albania 2020-01-13  100.00
Albania driving Albania 2020-01-14  95.30
Albania driving Albania 2020-01-15  101.43
Albania driving Albania 2020-01-16  97.20
Albania driving Albania 2020-01-17  103.55
Albania driving Albania 2020-01-18  112.67
```

However, I need to analyze the *transportation_type* with *country* and *region* so i did `pivot_wider` with this code:

```r
p_wide <- mobilityTrendData %>% 
    group_by(transportation_type) %>%
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = transportation_type, 
                values_from = daily_result) %>%
    select(-row)
```

Note: the column name 'value' was changed to 'daily_result' and the figures are already `scaled` from `value` column

This was the result:

```r
> summary(p_wide)
    region            country              date              driving         walking      
 Length:598230      Length:598230      Length:598230      Min.   :-2.09   Min.   :-2.1    
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.:-0.46   1st Qu.:-1.0    
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median : 0.00   Median :-0.3    
                                                          Mean   : 0.10   Mean   :-0.4    
                                                          3rd Qu.: 0.49   3rd Qu.: 0.1    
                                                          Max.   :25.60   Max.   :10.6    
                                                          NA's   :80070   NA's   :537880  
    transit      
 Min.   :-2.1    
 1st Qu.:-1.4    
 Median :-0.8    
 Mean   :-0.7    
 3rd Qu.:-0.1    
 Max.   : 5.2    
 NA's   :560490
```

I had NA's in majority of the rows in *driving*,*walking* and *transit*.
What could lead to this knowing fully well that there was no NA's in the previous dataset?

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I go with Andy Eggers explanation in the answer. When you `pivot_wider()`, the tibble will be based on all combinations of the columns you break out. Check your `long` tibble that each country has an entry for each day for each activity (walking, driving, transit). I am pretty sure the NAs come from the `missing` entries. Please note that if you correct NAs after your pivot_longer by imputing, this does not ensure that you have an entry for all combinations. That is something you would need to check (and impute). As Andy said: what you see is the feature of the data!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a date and a region/country combination where you have a value for `driving` but not for `walking`. Then when you `pivot_wider` you should have `NA` for `walking`. There was no `NA` in the long dataset, but there was effectively a missing row.

As for how to fix this problem: if I have understood the problem correctly, it is not a problem to fix but a feature of the data.

PS: I don't understand why you do the `group_by()` operation, or why you create and then drop the `row` variable. If I have missed something, I suspect it is the effect of the `group_by()` on `pivot_wider()`.

Comment: initially, i had missing values in the numeric column of my dataset when i load it R. I replaced the missing values with NA's  with this code: `mobilityTrendData[mobilityTrendData ==""]<-NA`  after `pivot_longer`, I replaced the NA's by the mean with this code: `mobilityTrendData$daily_result[is.na (mobilityTrendData$daily_result)]<- mean(mobilityTrendData$daily_result, na.rm = T)` .I used `group_by()` because i want `driving`, `walking` and `transit` to have a separate columns with values respectively. i droped the `row` because i think i dont need it.  I need a better way of doing this

Comment: I removed `group_by ()` i ran the code like this: `p_wide<-mobilityTrendData %>%   mutate(row = row_number())%>%pivot_wider(names_from = transportation_type, values_from = daily_result) %>%
  select(-row)`. I still have NA's in `walking`, `driving`, `transit` columns. My worry is that why do I have NA's in `pivot_wider` meanwhile there are no NA's in `pivot_longer` dataset? again, if i dont add this `mutate(row = row_number())`, i will have a very bad output  like this `<dbl [170]> <NULL> <NULL>` in all columns of `walking`, `driving`, `transit`. my goal is not to have NA's.